# PHP PDO Custom class ple

Tags: php, mysql, classes, pdo

i created a database class from a good tutorial and wanted to put it up here so it would get in some search results. it took me about 2 days to find it. also i added a few custom functions to it.. here it is :P and if there is something that can be done better or more proficiently please feel free to let me know.

```
config.php:

// Database Constants
defined('DB_HOST') ? NULL : define('DB_HOST', 'edit:host');
defined('DB_USER') ? NULL : define('DB_USER', 'edit:user');
defined('DB_PASS') ? NULL : define('DB_PASS', 'edit:pass');
defined('DB_NAME') ? NULL : define('DB_NAME', 'edit:databasename');
```

database.class.php:

```
class Database {

private $dbhost = DB_HOST;
private $dbuser = DB_USER;
private $dbpass = DB_PASS;
private $dbname = DB_NAME;
private $dbh;
private $error;
private $stmt;

public function __construct() {
    // set DSN
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->dbhost . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
    // set OPTIONS
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );
    // Create a new PDO instance
    try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $options);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function query($query) {
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}

public function selectQuery($table, $fields, $FieldToQuery, $value) {
    try {
        if ((gettype($fields) != 'array') || (gettype($value) != 'array')) {
            $fields = (array) $fields;
            $FieldToQuery = (array) $FieldToQuery;
            $value = (array) $value;
        }
        $holders = $FieldToQuery;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($holders); $i++) {
            $holders[$i] = ':' . $holders[$i];
        }
        $array = array_combine($holders, $value);
        $query = 'SELECT ' . implode(',', $fields) . ' FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE ' .
         implode(',',$FieldToQuery) . ' = ' . implode(',', $holders);
        $this->query($query);
        $this->bindArray($array);
        $rows = $this->resultset();
        return $rows;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function insertQuery($table, $fields, $values) {
    try {
        if ((gettype($fields) != 'array') || (gettype($values) != 'array')) {
            $fields = (array) $fields;
            $values = (array) $values;
        }
        $holders = $fields;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($holders); $i++) {
            $holders[$i] = ':' . $holders[$i];
        }
        $array = array_combine($holders, $values);
        $query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . '(' . implode(',', $fields)
                . ') VALUES (' . implode(',', $holders) . ')';
        $this->query($query);
        $this->bindArray($array);
        $this->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function bindArray($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $this->bind($key, $value);
    }
}

public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
    if (is_null($type)) {
        switch (true) {
            case is_int($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
            case is_bool($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
            case is_null($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
    }
    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}

public function execute() {
    $this->stmt->execute();
}

public function resultset() {
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function single() {
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function rowCount() {
    return $this->stmt->rowCount();
}

public function lastInsertId() {
    return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
}

public function beginTransaction() {
    return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
}

public function endTransaction() {
    return $this->dbh->commit();
}

public function cancelTransaction() {
    return $this->dbh->rollBack();
}

public function debugDumpParams() {
    return $this->stmt->debugDumpParams();
}

}
```

here is the link http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/

Comment: Code Review is meant for reviewing code that *you* wrote, not code that you found on the internet.

Comment: @svick: Looks like it's only partly tutorial code. The `bindArray`, `selectQuery`, and `insertQuery` methods look original.

Comment: @TraeMoore: Please don't change your code too much once you've posted the question; it makes the answers look like people are seeing things.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Those constants, `DB_HOST` etc, since there's no easy way to redefine them, pretty much ensure that you can only ever have one database per run of your app.  Maybe this is an issue for you; maybe it's not.  But it can be a showstopper if you have to use two databases.  I'd at least accept args for host, db, user, and password, and maybe default to the DB_ constants if the args are not set.  (Personally, i'd get rid of the constants altogether, but i can see some logic behind them...)

Your select query almost certainly fails for more than one field.  The standard syntax is `...WHERE field1 = value1 AND field2 = value2...` rather than `WHERE field1, field2... = value1, value2...`.

While you're at it, you might consider using an associative array to replace the two separate ones.  Maybe even for the insert as well.  `array('field1' => 'value1', 'field2' => value2, ...)` is a bit less error-prone than having two separate arrays, and it looks like `bindArray` already expects such an array anyway.

Maybe it's just me, but i don't see any way to retrieve `$error`.  Either provide a getter for it or just get rid of it altogether and let the exceptions propagate like you do with most of the other methods.  If you decide to keep it, you need to make sure to let the caller know to look at the error.  (The mostly-standard way of doing that is to return `false`.)  But really, you should probably just let the caller catch the exception, for consistency's sake; they'll have to do so for the rest of your methods anyway, and they shouldn't have to wonder how you're handling errors this time (or scratch their heads when they handle errors just like they do everywhere else, and aren't getting an exception back, but stuff's not working).

As far as your config script, it looks like the conditional operator is being abused.  It works, as `define` is a real function rather than a language construct...but it's still abuse.  The conditional operator is made for deciding between two values, which is why the `? NULL :` is there.

```
if (!defined('DB_HOST')) define('DB_HOST', 'hostname');
```

is easier to follow, and is even less to type.  :P

Comment: After reading this i see exactly what your saying and am going to figure out how to fix it so that i can still keep what i have. I do see what your saying about error's piling up. i do need to implement some sort of err solution... Forgive me for not catching all corners, ive only been doing php for about 2 weeks. – Trae Moore 5 mins ago..

Comment: You're forgiven... *this time...*  :)  Really, though, the point of this site is to bring up those details you hadn't thought about.  As long as you consider our suggestions, it's all good.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor is basically always creating the same instances, so you are not really using the class as an object. I would rather create a database class that can be used like:

```
$db = new Database('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'dbname');
```

and then instantiate it as:

```
$db = new Database(DB_HOST, DB_USER ...);
```

which will prevent you from having to refactor your class if in the future when you'll need to connect to multi databases.

Also you are using `$this->stmt` as the current statement just to save the:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('...');
```

which doesn't really make any sense and just reconvert the OOP of PDO back to the functional way of programming.

This:

```
public function rowCount() {
    return $this->stmt->rowCount();
}

public function lastInsertId() {
    return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
}

public function beginTransaction() {
    return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
}

public function endTransaction() {
    return $this->dbh->commit();
}

public function cancelTransaction() {
    return $this->dbh->rollBack();
}

public function debugDumpParams() {
    return $this->stmt->debugDumpParams();
}
```

is just useless and unmaintainable. Why don't you extend the PDO class instead?

PDO provides a good error handling via Exceptions and you are taking it away by saving it to a private property that is never even called. Why do you wan't to hide errors? Why don't you just let `PDOException`s being thrown? Or why don't you create a:

```
class DatabaseException extends Exception {}
```

exception class?

**tl;dr**: *think with objects*!

Comment: @cHao no i didn't.. your crazy :P

Comment: @TraeMoore: I have no idea what you're talking about.  :)

Comment: @cHao while this is fun, maybe you could give me some pointers? the first time i tried to make this class i used extends and ended up with nothing...

Comment: @jeffrey isn't surrounding things in try and catch error catching?

Comment: @TraeMoore: In this case, it's error *hiding*.  :P  Callers will be expecting to catch exceptions (cause that's how every other method works), and in a handful of methods you're sticking error messages in some whole other place that (a) you don't let callers know to check, and (b) they wouldn't have access to check even if they knew.  If you're not going to fix the problem, and don't have some cleanup to do, don't catch the exception.

Comment: @cHao can you link me on some articles.. i have no idea what you're saying...

Comment: @TraeMoore: I'm saying you should really decide whether you want to throw exceptions, return an error code, or what have you.  However you choose to do errors, *do it consistently.*  As it is, all those one-line methods that just call PDO functions will throw a PDOException if they fail, cause that's what your constructor is telling them to do (see `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE`).  But other methods are instead catching PDOExceptions and squirreling away the message, surprising anyone who *expects* an exception on failure (cause that's what happens everywhere else).

Comment: As for articles, i don't know of any.  Other than perhaps [the wikipedia article on POLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: @TraeMoore, the hell is going on here?